# I am using file upload control to upload a .doc file. How can I get number of pages in that uploaded .doc file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I am using file upload control to upload a .doc file. How can I get number of pages in that uploaded .doc file? I want the count of number of pages in that uploaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

### your .aspx page

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Upload" ID="btnupload" OnClick="BtnuploadClick" />
```

### your .aspx.cs page

```
protected void BtnuploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);

            var application = new Application();
            var document = application.Documents.Open(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);

            // Get the page count.
            var numberOfPages = document.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, false);

            StatusLabel.Text = string.Format("Total number of pages in document: {0}", numberOfPages);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

}
```

and don't forget to add reference of "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of pages couont of word file like this.

Add Reference of the Microsoft Office 2013 COM objects

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var application = new Application();

        // Open YOur word file path
        var document = application.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Demo.docx");

        // Get the page count.
        var numberOfPages = document.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, false);

        // Print out the result
        Console.WriteLine("Total number of pages in document: {0}", numberOfPages);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not able to find "Microsoft Office 2013 COM objects".

Comment: You have to add this assembly reference from Reference Manager Wizard.

Comment: I know that but i cannot find "Microsoft Office 2013 COM objects" their.

Comment: which version of visual studio you use?

Comment: Find Reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" from Reference manager Wizard

Comment: Thank a lot. I have found that reference. It works well with the local file that is reside on our drive.
But I want something like,
I have one fileupload control on page which is use for uploading a doc file. once i upload that file i have button on that page. How can i count the same on the button click event.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I got clear solution to my problem. Your solution is working perfectly.